# Accessing photos with facebook 4.4.1 SDK for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-processing

I'm just starting out with android development and using the Facebook SDK. I have followed online tutorials and successfully made an app that logs into facebook and now im trying to make an app that creates a new activity showing the profile picture of the user after logging in.

I'm trying to follow the facebook documentation for using the  SDK however it is rather vague and I was hoping to find a better example. All I can find is the following example code:

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/photos",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I'm fine with all the access token stuff but I have no idea how to handle the result. How can save the images from "response" and how can I display these images in a new activity? A link to a relevant example would be really helpful. I've been looking for hours and found nothing related recent versions of the SDK.